# $P \subseteq$ Aut($G$), $Q \in$ Syl$_{q}(G)$. Show $\sigma(Q) = Q$ for all $\sigma \in P$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a finite group with $|G|>1$, and suppose $P \subseteq $Aut($G$)  is a $p$-subgroup. Show that there exists some nontrivial Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ (for some prime $q$) such that $\sigma(Q)= Q$ for all $\sigma \in P$.

The author's hint (Martin Isaacs, Algebra, p.67 #5.6) asks us to work on two cases: $p \mid |G|$ and $p \nmid |G|$.

Please post only an outline/hint on how I should approach this. I want to try to work out the details myself.

Comment: It would help if you show your working so far :)

Comment: Sure, I think I have the case $p \nmid |G|$. If $P$ acts on $Q$ then the size of the orbit would have to divide $n_q$, the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups, which in turn divides $|G|$. But that cannot be since $p \nmid |G|$. Hence the orbit size is 1, and $\sigma(Q) = Q$ $\forall \sigma \in P$. I am unsure about the other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For every $q$, the group $P$ acts on the set of $q$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Whenever a $p$-group acts on a set $X$, the cardinality of $X$ is congruent to the number of elements fixed by the entire $p$-group, modulo $p$. So, if $|X|$ is not divisible by $p$, then there is a fixed point. Now try to say something about the cardinality of the set of $q$-Sylow subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Thank you. This is very similar to what I have thus far (please see above). I presume this could be used for both the cases?

Comment: @Wulfgang: Yes.

Comment: I am still unsure how I should resolve the case when $p \mid |G|$. Now $G$ has a Sylow-$p$ subgroup, and the argument I used above for the $p \nmid |G|$ case doesn't help.

Comment: @Wulfgang: For the case $p \mid |G|$, take $q=p$ and use Sylow 3.

Comment: Thanks, so much. For some reason I assumed $q$ must to be distinct from $p$.